# How to decode an attachment chunked filename in javamail?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to figure out how to manage an attachment of a mail that has the filename chunked. I am on java 1.6 with javamail 1.5.1 and my code can manage all kind of mails but when I receive one from a specific adress(i can't talk with those guys) it doesn't import some attachments properly. When I open those atachments(assuming that this one's name is filename without extension.extension) with notepad I find this:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
    name*0="filename without extension"; name*1=.extension
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
    filename*0="filename without extension"; filename*1=.extension
```

before the base64 content. I tried to search for similar problems but I have the exact filename but it's splitted and the `BodyPart.getFilename()` method returns null. I was thinking about taking the whole header and work on that.

Answer (score 1):

This should be supported by your version of Javamail.

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.decodeparameters", "true");
```

For more info, search for "RFC 2231" on the package documentation of `javax.mail.internet`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html

Comment: I tried setting those properties(also decodefilename) when the cycle find an attachment but didn't help,getfilename still returns null.

Comment: @Frattak These are System properties. You need to set them at the beginning of your program, not just when you find an attachment - it's probably too late at that point as the parsing was already done.

Comment: RFC 2231 support should be enabled by default starting with JavaMail 1.5.0.  Are you sure you're using JavaMail 1.5.1?  Also, you might want to upgrade to the current version, [JavaMail 1.6.0](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks